# Using an NSMutableArray instead of an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've recently come to learn that `NSFetchedResultsController` is an extremely buggy class and its been causing me headaches for a while now with my rather large Core Data app.

Would it be appropriate to use an `NSMutableArray` to feed the table view instead of an `NSFetchedResultsController`? What I'm talking about is, temporarily creating a fetched results controller to grab the objects from my managed object context, creating a new `NSMutableArray` with the `fetchedObjects` from the fetched results controller, then using that to feed my table view.

Are there any benefits to using `NSFetchedResultsController` directly over an `NSMutableArray` to supply data to my table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a fetched results controller. It is a new convenience class and you can always do things old school.

I presume that because you want to use mutable array that you intend to use add and remove objects. This is not a problem except you have to everything manually. If something else modifies the data, you have to register notifications to monitor the changes and refetch as needed.