# Editing multiple objects in CoreData's fetchedObjects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, magicalrecord

Quite simply I want to iterate through CoreData's `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` (More specifically I am using MagicalRecord in this example) and change all items that match my criteria (the if statement), then make changes to those objects.

```
for (Task *aTask in [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy]) {
    if ([aTask.day past] && [[aTask isArchived] isEqual:@(NO)]) {

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
        [context MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            aTask.day = date;
        }];
    }
}
```

But as it turns out it doesn't work! I am trying a solution where I don't have to manually manage everything CoreData as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172379/using-an-nsmutablearray-instead-of-an-nsfetchedresultscontroller) specifies and instead find a succinct solution to the problem, few lines of code and not much iteration.

**EDIT:** Following from Dan's answer, I have edited my imperfect code to...

```
NSPredicate *uncompletedTasks = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"day < %@ AND isArchived = %@",[NSDate date],@NO]]];
self.fetchedResultsController = [Task MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"dateScheduled" ascending:YES withPredicate:uncompletedTasks groupBy:nil delegate:self inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];

for (Task *aTask in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
    aTask.day = date;
}

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
[context MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {}];
```

This solves the problem, although only momentarily when I update the view, I get this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  ***
>   -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172379/using-an-nsmutablearray-instead-of-an-nsfetchedresultscontroller) with userInfo (null)

Comment: why are you setting a delegate for this FRC?

Comment: there is no need for a "full fledged" FRC here, can't you just perform a fetch to get all the objects `[context executeFetchRequest:...]` or `[Task "objects answering predicate ..."]`?

Comment: But will that change anything? Won't it be the same result as a "full fledged" FRC. Less code though.

Comment: try setting the delegate to nil

Comment: I tried removing `MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion` and that solved it. The entries are automatically updated, I didn't have to save them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really know nothing about MagicalRecord, but ...

If you iterate through all items fetched by the FRC just to make an update to some of them you better:

1) perform the update in the background
2) fetch only the objects you need updated. example predicate:

```
NSPredicate* needUpdate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"day < %@ AND isArchived = %@",[NSDate date],@NO];
NSPredicate* p = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[FRC_predicate,needUpdate]];
```

3. perform a single save after you updated all objects (or in batches, don't save one by one)

Guessing ...
You wrote code that make an update to an object (`aTask.day = date;`) in a completion block.
This might not actually persist the change the way you think it does.
make the update before you call the "save" procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems here.

First, I am not sure why you need `mutableCopy`. You are not modifying the members of the array yo are iterating through, so this should not be necessary. I am not even sure what the effect of making a managed object copy is in this case. Just leave it out.

Second, your boolean comparison is a bit confusing and can be written in a  simpler way. This should be enough:

```
"... && aTalk.isArchived.boolValue"
```

Third, you are changing the object in the completion block after the save. So you are not saving the change, just perhaps the previous one made in some earlier iteration through the loop. Instead, just write the change and call save after the loop.

When saving, make sure the used context is the same as that of the fetched results controller.